# My number converter(decimal to base 2-16) prints numbers in opposite order

Tags: c

I've been working on a program that, when executed, asks for two numbers, the first being any decimal number, the second number being the base (2-16) which you wish to convert to. It works great, except one thing. Every output is backwards. Which is to be expected, it takes remainders and outputs them in the order they are calculated. However I want them to come out in the opposite order. I was thinking about setting up a loop and having the remainders stored in an array, then loop through the array backwards and spit out the information. But I'm new to C and i cannot get it to work! Tell me what you think!

Any help would be very appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

  int x, y, z, c; //Sets up variables to be used in program


  printf("Please enter two integers: "); //Asks for user input
  scanf("%d", &x);
  scanf("%d", &y); //stores input

  printf("%d\n", x);
  printf("%d\n", y);
  printf(" \n");

  if(y < 2 || y > 16){
    printf("You have entered incorrect information.\n");
           return 0;
  } //bug checks

  else if(y > 1 && y < 17){

    while(x != 0){
       c = (x%y);
       x = (x/y); // Loops numbers until a 0 value is reached, can be used with
                  // any Base

     if( c == 10){
        c = printf("A");
    }else if( c == 11){
        c = printf("B");
    }else if( c == 12){
        c = printf("C");
    }else if( c == 13){
        c = printf("D");
    }else if( c == 14){
        c = printf("E");
    }else if( c == 15){
        c = printf("F");
    }else{
        printf("%d", c);
    }
        // Returns for each remainer option
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
     // Returns for each remainer option
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was a residual edit I was working on. Forgot to comment it out...

Comment: I believe you can change your big if-else-if-printf block into just:  `printf("%X", c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
int i = 0;
int rev[50];
```

and change your code as

```
if( c == 10){
    rev[i++] = 'A' ;
}else if( c == 11){
    rev[i++] = 'B' ;
}else if( c == 12){
    rev[i++] = 'C' ;
}else if( c == 13){
    rev[i++] = 'D' ;
}else if( c == 14){
    rev[i++] = 'E' ;
}else if( c == 15){
    rev[i++] = 'F' ;
}else{
    rev[i++] = 48 + c;
}
    // Returns for each remainer option
}
printf("\n");
}
while(--i >= 0) 
    printf("%c", rev[i]);
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why you loaded the rev array with 50?

Comment: it just has to have enough space to accommodate all integer options right?

Comment: Thank you for the help! I cannot express how much you've helped me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the remainders into an character array and print the array in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be a recursive approach (which I wouldn't recommend for very long sequences, but since an integer has a limited number of digits, you can know how deep your recursion would be). It would look something like this (not tested, and somewhat pseudo-codey):

```
printnum(int n, int b)
{ int r;

  if (n < b)
    output n;
  else
  { r = n % b;
    printnum(n/b, b)
    output r;
  }
}
```

A good optimizer might even be able to transparently convert that to non-recursive code when you compile.